# How to fix 'Extra attributes from the server: style' warning in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm create a React template use nextjs, but here is a warning `Extra attributes from the server: style`. I don`t use style attributes in my template. How can I fix this?

Comment: **Check this answer, this might help** https://stackoverflow.com/a/72878149/14041648

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After a bit of investigation, I found that the error was coming from an input component in my app. Specifically, for an input where `type="password"`. I'm using LastPass so I tried turning it off and running the app again, and that seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Wikiwand doing the same for me. In this case with chrome I was able to change it from "run on all sites" to "https://*.wikipedia.org/*" and it still works fine.

Answer (score 11):

Try to disable all your extensions. If problem is gone, you can try enabling it one by one to find out which extension causes the error.

I solved the same problem like this - had:

> Warning: Extra attributes from the server: class at body at html at
> ReactDevOverlay