# When i build my next js app, css files doesn't get last changes

Tags: css, node.js, next.js

i've got this problem, i have a Next.js App on my client that works well (and if i do npm run build and see if the build works with node server js, all is fine).

The problem occurs when i move on production server my app. If i execute npm run build (on the server), my site works (Html files, links etc.) except for css files that doesn't get last changes (they have the old code).

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

[Package json code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Q5b.png)

[source code of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idBai.png)

Comment: most likely your css is built as well, look for other command in `package.json` and see if you need to build them.

Comment: @windmaomao Of which "other command" you are talking about?
I've added in the question above the package json code if you want to see it :-)

Comment: Try to hard refresh  your browser ? and comment the result please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, i've solved this problem. Css files were ok, the problem was that a css class had these wrong rules (not written by me):

```
-webkit-flex: 0 1 40%;
-ms-flex: -1 1 40%;
flex: -1 1 40%;
```

Rules that on my client, on chrome were working fine (taking the prefix webkit-flex) but once that i build the app, these prefix were removed; infact looking the builded app chrome was applying the flex wrong rule (flex: -1 1 40%;) not the prefix one (-webkit-flex: 0 1 40%;).

I fixed the error removing those prefixes, and correcting the flex rule like this:

```
flex: 0 1 40%;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is an improper file import issue!**

In case if you imported the css file as below

```
import styles from '../styles/component.module.css'
```

Better change it to

```
import styles from '../styles/Component.module.css'
```

Make sure you are using class naming style to name **Component.module.css** file

This will change will make sure your Component.module.css file is compiled on every bit on code change in the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it shows you this message

***Warning: Extra attributes from the server: data-theme,style***
Add the atribute to the html tag

**suppressHydrationWarning**

as